# Error on running a project after installing a package

Tags: reactjs

I was running my project finely, but I merge my code with other which contain a package called react-modal, after that my code doesn't work. I revert that code from my project, but it doesn't work, I can't even run my project. "cannot read properties of undefined" error is occuring. I upgrade all my packages like webpack, webpack cli etc, but it doesn't helps. What I need to do to run my project?

Comment: Have you tried deleting node_modules and create it again?

Comment: what was the last version of react on which your project worked?

Comment: Run `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: @Yossi ya I tried that

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar It is the latest version

Comment: @AkshayMulgavkar Okay, Let me check

Comment: Please add the full text of the error

Comment: Maybe it is because you updated webpack that your project doesn't run even after reverting the other's code.

Comment: Also it maybe because you don't have the right node or npm version that you couldnot make the code work at the first place. Ask your coworker which version he is using.

Comment: `rm` is  not a command error occured @AkshayMulgavkar

Comment: basically, `rm -rf node_modules` deletes the node module folder from the directory and `npm install` installs it again. You can manually delete the node_modules folder and just run `npm install` @Levina make sure all these commands are run inside your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do two things here.
First to revert your code back to your latest code before merge.
Run the below command to delete Node_modules npm prune --production 
and then run npm install and then build your project.